# SQL query for exclude records data

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I need help to find query for exclude some records data.
My data is like :

```
Pin      Device          Date Time
1         A-in           01/01/2023 10.00
1         B-Out          01/01/2023 10.30
2         B-in           01/01/2023 11.00
2         A-Out          01/01/2023 11.30
3         C-In           01/01/2023 13.00
```

I want to show rows where device for a pin has 'In' but not 'Out'.
in above example Pin 3 has 'C-In' but no 'C-out'

```
Pin      Device          Date Time
3         C-In           01/01/2023 13.00
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have formatted the data pieces in the question, but someone will need to approve.

Comment: what is the criteria for selection of that record?  By 'Device' or by 'Pin'?  You can have `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Device = 'C-In'` or `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Pin = 3` based on your criteria of selection. Or similarly on both columns or even date-time.

Comment: Divide `Device` column to two colums (devide and direction) then group and select the group by device where there is no 'Out' in direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch those `*-in` rows where there does not exists a later `*-Out` row:

```
select * 
from pins p
where p.Device like '%-in' and not exists (
  select * 
  from pins o
  where trim(trailing '-Out' from o.Device)=trim(trailing '-in' from p.Device) and o.Device like '%-Out' 
  and o.DateTime>=p.DateTime
)
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XGWs63i9).

Note that in your data `B-in` comes after `B-Out`. It is therefore included in the result set.

Comment: `o.Device=o.Device` is always true. Do you mean `p.Pin=o.Pin`?

Comment: @danblack Fixed the query. Thanks for pointing it out.